# Replace missing values in one table to values in another table by joining column name to row

Tags: r, missing-data

I am trying to replace missing values in one table to values in another table by joining column name to row. Below is an example:

df1

```
A  B  C  D
1  3  4  *
4  *  5  9
0  *  2  *
1  2  *  4
```

df2

```
Variable  Value
A  2
B  1
C  9
D  0
```

Result data set:

```
A  B  C  D
1  3  4  0
4  1  5  9
0  1  2  0
1  2  9  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
df1[as.character(df2$Variable)] <- Map(function(x, y)
    replace(x, is.na(x), y), df1[as.character(df2$Variable)], df2$Value)
```

If the values are not `NA` and just `*` then

```
df1[as.character(df2$Variable)] <- Map(function(x, y)
    replace(x, x=="*", y), df1[as.character(df2$Variable)], df2$Value)
df1
#  A B C D
#1 1 3 4 0
#2 4 1 5 9
#3 0 1 2 0
#4 1 2 9 4
```

If the dataset 'df1' is not character, then do

```
df1[] <- as.matrix(df1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), B = c("3", "*", "*", "2"
 ), C = c("4", "5", "2", "*"), D = c("*", "9", "*", "4")), .Names = c("A", 
 "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
df2 <- structure(list(Variable = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Value = c(2L, 
 1L, 9L, 0L)), .Names = c("Variable", "Value"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: This is showing error: Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

Comment: @shivanigupta You should show the dput of your data.  I am not getting any error with this

Comment: @shivanigupta  I updated with the data I used.  Please check if you get the error on the data in my post

Comment: Yeah, I think I made some syntax error. It is working fine. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `stack` and `unstack`,

```
d1 <- stack(df)
d1$values[d1$values == '*'] <- df1$Value[match(d1$ind, df1$Variable)][d1$values == '*']
unstack(d1, values ~ ind)
#  A B C D
#1 1 3 4 0
#2 4 1 5 9
#3 0 1 2 0
#4 1 2 9 4
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(A = c(1, 4, 0, 1), B = c("3", "*", "*", "2"), 
    C = c("4", "5", "2", "*"), D = c("*", "9", "*", "4")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

dput(df1)
structure(list(Variable = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Value = c(2L, 
1L, 9L, 0L)), .Names = c("Variable", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Finding out the column names of "*" and matching that with `Variable` column in `df2` and extracting the corresponding `Value`.

```
x <- which(df1=="*", arr.ind = TRUE)
df1[x] <- df2$Value[match(names(df1)[x[, 2]], df2$Variable)]

#  A B C D
#1 1 3 4 0
#2 4 1 5 9
#3 0 1 2 0
#4 1 2 9 4
```

This is assuming you have character columns in `df1`, if they are not convert them by

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create lookup table then update on match:

```
# make a lookup table same size as df1
df2Lookup <-
  matrix(rep(df2$Value, nrow(df1)), nrow = nrow(df1), byrow = TRUE)

# then update on "*"
df1[ df1 == "*" ] <- df2Lookup[ df1 == "*" ]

#result
df1
#   A B C D
# 1 1 3 4 0
# 2 4 1 5 9
# 3 0 1 2 0
# 4 1 2 9 4
```